# geolocation doesn't work with android after building with phonegap

Tags: android, html, cordova, geolocation

i am workin on application for android that will use watch position but it didnt work with android i dont now the problem 
i am bulding the app from the phonegap.com website not from eclips .
this is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Device Properties Example</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="phonegap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

// Wait for Cordova to load
//
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

var watchID = null;

// Cordova is ready
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    // Get the most accurate position updates available on the
    // device.
    var options = { enableHighAccuracy: true };
    watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onSuccess, onError, options);
}

// onSuccess Geolocation
//
function onSuccess(position) {
    var element = document.getElementById('geolocation');
    element.innerHTML = 'Latitude: '  + position.coords.latitude      + '<br />' +
                        'Longitude: ' + position.coords.longitude     + '<br />' +
                        '<hr />'      + element.innerHTML;
}

// clear the watch that was started earlier
// 
function clearWatch() {
    if (watchID != null) {
        navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(watchID);
        watchID = null;
    }
}

// onError Callback receives a PositionError object
//
function onError(error) {
  alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
        'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<p id="geolocation">Watching geolocation...</p>
<button onclick="clearWatch();">Clear Watch</button>     
</body>
</html>
```

and this is my config file
    
    http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
        xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
        id        = "com.phonegap.hello-world"
        version   = "2.2.0">
    Makanak

```
<description>
    Makanak is a location based application heple u to fin places in Egypt.
</description>

<author>
    Makanak Team
</author>

<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/device" />

<preference name="phonegap-version" value="2.2.0" />
<preference name="orientation"      value="default" />
<preference name="target-device"    value="universal" />
<preference name="fullscreen"       value="false" />

<icon src="icon.png" />
<icon src="res/icon/android/icon-36-ldpi.png"   gap:platform="android"            gap:density="ldpi" />
<icon src="res/icon/android/icon-48-mdpi.png"   gap:platform="android"    gap:density="mdpi" />
<icon src="res/icon/android/icon-72-hdpi.png"   gap:platform="android"    gap:density="hdpi" />
<icon src="res/icon/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png"  gap:platform="android"    gap:density="xhdpi" />
<icon src="res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png"     gap:platform="blackberry" />
<icon src="res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png"     gap:platform="blackberry" gap:state="hover"/>
<icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-57.png"            gap:platform="ios"        width="57"    height="57" />
<icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-72.png"            gap:platform="ios"        width="72" height="72" />
<icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-57-2x.png"         gap:platform="ios"        width="114" height="114" />
<icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-72-2x.png"         gap:platform="ios"        width="144" height="144" />
<icon src="res/icon/webos/icon-64.png"          gap:platform="webos" />
<icon src="res/icon/windows-phone/icon-48.png"  gap:platform="winphone" />
<icon src="res/icon/windows-phone/icon-173.png" gap:platform="winphone"   gap:role="background" />

<gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png"  gap:platform="android" gap:density="ldpi" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png"  gap:platform="android" gap:density="mdpi" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png"  gap:platform="android" gap:density="hdpi" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="xhdpi" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/blackberry/screen-225.png"         gap:platform="blackberry" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait.png"    gap:platform="ios"     width="320" height="480" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png" gap:platform="ios"     width="640" height="960" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-portrait.png"      gap:platform="ios"     width="768" height="1024" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png"     gap:platform="ios"     width="1024" height="768" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/windows-phone/screen-portrait.jpg" gap:platform="winphone" />
</widget>
```

do i have to write Permissions when building from phonegap website ?!!!

Android

app/res/xml/config.xml

app/AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

You must add geolocation feature:

```
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/geolocation"/>
```

Comment: thanxx for your help and sorry for my late , where to add this geolocation future in index, config.xml or .... ?

Comment: Yes, you must add feature in config.xml for phonegap build